# Electron - simpler way of communicating between windows?

Tags: electron

I need to build a web based interface for a **quick** personal project and I'd like to use electron.

It's essentially a kind of gaming Zoom app with lots of bells and whistles.

The problem is, I **need** to have a main window that will run in fullscreen, which I capture with OBS and broadcast to a popular streaming service.

I also need another window, what I refer to as the Control Panel, to control elements in the main window that I work with behind-the-scenes, for showing graphics, playing sound effects, controlling video settings etc.

If I were to code this app for a web browser, I would have absolutely no problem, as I can create the secondary window from my main window (window.open) and the 2 windows can easily refer to one another and their documents.

In electron however, windows are essentially contained boxes. Communication between 2 windows has to be channelled via ipc essentially as encoded commands and interpreted by the main process...

So to control loads of elements and entities from my control panel, I'd either have to implement a complex messaging system, which frankly seems MASSIVELY unnecessary, or to be hacky I could simply issue javascript commands as strings to the other window with BrowserWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript()... but *yuck*.

I could also contain all the logic-y stuff in the main process, but again, this still requires a messaging system that I don't have the time to implement.

I guess I want to know if there's a better way.

I'm just imagining a scenario win which a developer has written a web-app that uses multiple windows and lots of direct window-to-window communication, and now they need to migrate it to electron... how would they best go about it without re-writing a ton of code?

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer, '`nativeWindowOpen`':

```
main_window = new electron.BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        nativeWindowOpen: true
    }
});
```

I can now use window.open() from my main window and refer directly back and forth.

So now I can do this:

```
control_panel = window.open("./control_panel.html", "Control Panel", "width=720,height=480")
console.log(control_panel.document)
```

And from the opened window:

```
console.log(window.opener.document)
```

And I can refer to variables and document elements.

I couldn't find anyone mentioning this useful 'nativeWindowOpen' option when I was scouring stackoverflow et al earlier, only found it by reading documentation.